# How to return the inner collection of each result

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query that is return all users that look like:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual List<Location> Locations {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have a list of users as a result, but I just want to return the Locations for each user, how can I do this?

```
var users = repository.FindAll();
```

So for each user, I want to return the Location collection.

Comment: Do you want to have single list containing all locations or list of location lists?

Comment: @Aleksandar I want a single list of all locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about your question, but Entity Framework coupled with your repository should return an active collection of your object. If the syntax does generate a valid object, then I'm under the assumption you have the following with data.

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

You could simply do:

```
var locations = users.GetAllUsers()
                     .Select(user => user.Locations)
                     .SelectMany(location => location)
                     .Distinct();
```

So select the location object, then flatten it for desired data, then distinct to remove duplicates.  So you would receive all the locations associated to your users.  You can mix and match Linq to accomplish this a bunch of different ways.  I may have syntax or reversed `Select` and `SelectMany` since I keep getting interrupted but this should at least help you.

Answer (score 2):

First you should extract all locations afterwards you should merge it into single list

```
var mergedList = MergeLists(users.Select(x => x.Locations).ToList());
```

MergeLists looks like this

```
    List<Location> MergeLists(List<List<Location>> listsOfLists)
    {
        List<Location> mergedList = new List<Location>();
        foreach (List<Location> listLocation in listsOfLists)
        {
            mergedList.AddRange(listLocation);
        }
        return mergedList;
    }
```

EDIT.
More elegant solution

```
users.Select(x => x.Locations).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: You understood the question differently, but that might be what he is attempting to ask for.

Comment: Can't I use SelectMany for this?

Comment: @cool breeze Yes, you are absolutely right, sleepiness made me forget about it :), updated my answer.

Comment: @coolbreeze Yeah, my answer has `Select` / `SelectMany` approach rather than merged list.

Comment: You can simplify it even further: `users.SelectMany(x => x.Locations).ToList();`